# Find a specific summation $\sum^{i-1}_{k=1} k \frac{2a(n-(k-1))!}{(k-1-r_1)!(k-1-r_2)!(k-1-r_3)!}$

Tags: calculus, summation

Please find a specific summation as follows.

$\sum^{i-1}_{k=1} k \frac{2a(n-(k-1))!}{(k-1-r_1)!(k-1-r_2)!(k-1-r_3)!}$

Calculate the sum the specific equation, which has k, denominator with three factorials and nominator with one factorial.
Please help to find a solution. Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if the relations between $r_{1}$, $r_{2}$, $r_{3}$, $n$, and $i$ were stated. Any of  the $r_{j}$ values could truncate the series.

Comment: This looks like some hypergeometric function.